# Camera preview image data processing with Android L and Camera2 API

Tags: android, image-processing, camera, preview, android-5.0-lollipop

I'm working on an android app that is processing the input image from the camera and displays it to the user. This is fairly simple, I register a `PreviewCallback` on the camera object with the `setPreviewCallbackWithBuffer`.
This is easy and works smoothly with the old camera API

```
public void onPreviewFrame(byte[] data, Camera cam) {
    // custom image data processing
}
```

I'm trying to port my app to take advantage of the new Camera2 API and I'm not sure how exactly shall I do that. I followed the Camera2Video in L Preview samples that allows to record a video. However, there is no direct image data transfer in the sample, so I don't understand where exactly shall I get the image pixel data and how to process it.

Could anybody help me or suggest the way how one can get the the functionality of `PreviewCallback` in android L, or how it's possible to process preview data from the camera before displaying it to the screen? (there is no preview callback on the camera object)

Thank you!

Comment: have u sorted this problem.

Comment: Yes, I did. Check VP's response and also Camera2Basic and Camera2Video from android samples.
You need to create an ImageReader and use `setOnImageAvailableListener` to get a new image when captured. In order to draw image I created OpenGL surface which renders texture and a shader that converts `YUV_420_888` to `RGB`.

Comment: Thanks, I have checked both repos and VP response. When I set addTarget(mImageReader.getSurface()); It gives only three frames onImageAvailable after that it freezes the preview.

Comment: This (or something similar) can happen when you don't read/close the image from the ImageReader. Make sure that in the listener `onImageAvailable(...)` you do read and close the image. The Listener cannot be empty, even if you don't use the image you need to read it (for example with `reader.acquireNextImage()`).

Comment: Thanks @bubo. It took me a while to figure out this behavior because it was not mentioned in documentation.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Since the `Camera2` API is very different from the current `Camera` API, it might help to go through the documentation.

A good starting point is `camera2basic` example. It demonstrates how to use `Camera2` API and configure `ImageReader` to get JPEG images and register `ImageReader.OnImageAvailableListener` to receive those images

To receive preview frames, you need to add your `ImageReader`'s surface to `setRepeatingRequest`'s `CaptureRequest.Builder`.

Also, you should set `ImageReader`'s format to `YUV_420_888`, which will give you 30fps at 8MP (The documentation guarantees 30fps at 8MP for Nexus 5).

Comment: Hello, @VP.

Could you please advise me how to convert YUV_420_888 Image, that I receive in onImageAvailable listener, to Bitmap?

Comment: Here you go: Size largest = Collections.max(Arrays.asList(map.getOutputSizes(ImageFormat.YUV_420_888)),
                        new CompareSizesByArea());

Instead of .JPEG -- this is from the camera2Basic repo base.

Comment: @Ruban I added a response with code below based on VP's answer to clarify this implementation: http://stackoverflow.com/a/43564630/630996

Comment: Even while using `YUV_420_888` the preview of the camera is significantly lagging (in comparison with Camera1's `PreviewCallback`) and producing no more than 10 FPS on Moto G3 (while producing more than 30 FPS with same resolution on Camera1). Is it a known issue?

Comment: If you suffer low frame rate by Camera2 check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/51083567/2606068
good luck.@DmitryZaytsev

Comment: **ImageReader to get JPEG** and **ImageReader's format to YUV_420_888** doesn't make sense

Comment: it's slow https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51579859/camera2-set-preview-view-and-get-preview-callbacks

Comment: @VP I have followed your approach, But still no success. I am have tried on TEMPLATE_RECORD and TEMPLATE_PREVIEW as well.

Comment: I am setting up 2 surfaces one is Preview and other ImageReader (with YUV_420_888 format). As and when I start preview. Preview paused and received 5-7 callback on the onImageAvailable.

Answer (score 34):

Combining a few answers into a more digestible one because @VP's answer, while technically clear, is difficult to understand if it's your first time moving from Camera to Camera2:

Using https://github.com/googlesamples/android-Camera2Basic as a starting point, modify the following:

In `createCameraPreviewSession()` init a new `Surface` from `mImageReader`

```
Surface mImageSurface = mImageReader.getSurface();
```

Add that new surface as a output target of your `CaptureRequest.Builder` variable.  Using the Camera2Basic sample, the variable will be `mPreviewRequestBuilder`

```
mPreviewRequestBuilder.addTarget(mImageSurface);
```

Here's the snippet with the new lines (see my @AngeloS comments):

```
private void createCameraPreviewSession() {

    try {

        SurfaceTexture texture = mTextureView.getSurfaceTexture();
        assert texture != null;

        // We configure the size of default buffer to be the size of camera preview we want.
        texture.setDefaultBufferSize(mPreviewSize.getWidth(), mPreviewSize.getHeight());

        // This is the output Surface we need to start preview.
        Surface surface = new Surface(texture);

        //@AngeloS - Our new output surface for preview frame data
        Surface mImageSurface = mImageReader.getSurface();

        // We set up a CaptureRequest.Builder with the output Surface.
        mPreviewRequestBuilder = mCameraDevice.createCaptureRequest(CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_PREVIEW);

        //@AngeloS - Add the new target to our CaptureRequest.Builder
        mPreviewRequestBuilder.addTarget(mImageSurface);

        mPreviewRequestBuilder.addTarget(surface);

        ...
```

Next, in `setUpCameraOutputs()`, change the format from `ImageFormat.JPEG` to `ImageFormat.YUV_420_888` when you init your `ImageReader`. (PS, I also recommend dropping your preview size for smoother operation - one nice feature of Camera2)

```
mImageReader = ImageReader.newInstance(largest.getWidth() / 16, largest.getHeight() / 16, ImageFormat.YUV_420_888, 2);
```

Finally, in your `onImageAvailable()` method of `ImageReader.OnImageAvailableListener`, be sure to use @Kamala's suggestion because the preview will stop after a few frames if you don't close it

```
    @Override
    public void onImageAvailable(ImageReader reader) {

        Log.d(TAG, "I'm an image frame!");

        Image image =  reader.acquireNextImage();

        ...

        if (image != null)
            image.close();
    }
```

Comment: I got `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: submitRequestList:216: Request targets Surface that is not part of current capture session`, but using Google's [CameraView](https://github.com/google/cameraview) instead of Camera2Basic.

Comment: In the above code snippet, one can process/modify the image inside the `onImageAvailable` function.  This, however, won't display the image in preview. Right? How to display the image on the preview(`TextureView`) after processing is done?

Comment: I have tried your approach, But preview gets paused and receiving only a few callbacks of onImageAvailable.

Comment: The defined surface needs to be added to the list send to createCaptureSession - just like the preview surface already there - that is if you have a preview showing.

Answer (score 16):

In the ImageReader.OnImageAvailableListener class, close the image after reading as shown below (this will release the buffer for next capture).  You will have to handle exception on close

```
      Image image =  imageReader.acquireNextImage();
      ByteBuffer buffer = image.getPlanes()[0].getBuffer();
      byte[] bytes = new byte[buffer.remaining()];
      buffer.get(bytes);
      image.close();
```

Comment: This is a very useful snippet

Comment: How can you do that on each frame ?

Comment: This is only corrent when you use JPEG format to create ImageReader, or there will be more than one planes in the image

Answer (score 9):

I needed the same thing, so I used their example and added a call to a new function when the camera is in preview state.

```
private CameraCaptureSession.CaptureCallback mCaptureCallback
            = new CameraCaptureSession.CaptureCallback()
    private void process(CaptureResult result) {
        switch (mState) {
            case STATE_PREVIEW: {
                    if (buttonPressed){
                        savePreviewShot();
                    }
                break;
            }
```

The `savePreviewShot()` is simply a recycled version of the original `captureStillPicture()` adapted to use the preview template.

```
   private void savePreviewShot(){
        try {
            final Activity activity = getActivity();
            if (null == activity || null == mCameraDevice) {
                return;
            }
            // This is the CaptureRequest.Builder that we use to take a picture.
            final CaptureRequest.Builder captureBuilder =
                    mCameraDevice.createCaptureRequest(CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_PREVIEW);
            captureBuilder.addTarget(mImageReader.getSurface());

            // Orientation
            int rotation = activity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRotation();
            captureBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.JPEG_ORIENTATION, ORIENTATIONS.get(rotation));

            CameraCaptureSession.CaptureCallback CaptureCallback
                    = new CameraCaptureSession.CaptureCallback() {

                @Override
                public void onCaptureCompleted(CameraCaptureSession session, CaptureRequest request,
                                               TotalCaptureResult result) {
                    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd_HH:mm:ss:SSS");
                    Date resultdate = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis());
                    String mFileName = sdf.format(resultdate);
                    mFile = new File(getActivity().getExternalFilesDir(null), "pic "+mFileName+" preview.jpg");

                    Log.i("Saved file", ""+mFile.toString());
                    unlockFocus();
                }
            };

            mCaptureSession.stopRepeating();
            mCaptureSession.capture(captureBuilder.build(), CaptureCallback, null);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    };
```

Comment: I'm using your solution. The problem is that the camera2basic application (https://github.com/googlesamples/android-Camera2Basic), gets stuck after the first image capture. Did you solve this?

Comment: In addition, the image saving should be done outside the Ui thread

Comment: Yes, I changed the line mCaptureSession.capture(captureBuilder.build(), CaptureCallback, null); to            mCaptureSession.capture(captureBuilder.build(), mCaptureCallback, mBackgroundHandler);

Comment: is savePreviewShot actually saving the preview frame that is visible, or is it capturing the next available frame?  createCaptureRequest implies future?

Comment: A single preview frame spends very little time being visible. :) The frames are flowing all the time (approx. 30 frames/sec on my fastest device). However, the device can manage to save only few of them (eg. 5-6), so you could say that 1 in 6 frames gets saved.

Comment: In your onCaptureCompleted how do you actually save the data?

Comment: You don't save it there. You can use `ImageReader` for that. When an image is available you can trigger a separate thread to save the file, so your main thread is not burdened with it. You can find plenty of examples online.

Answer (score 2):

It's better to init `ImageReader` with max image buffer is `2` then use `reader.acquireLatestImage()` inside `onImageAvailable()`.

Because `acquireLatestImage()` will acquire the latest Image from the ImageReader's queue, dropping older one. This function is recommended to use over `acquireNextImage()` for most use-cases, as it's more suited for **real-time** processing. Note that max image buffer should be at least `2`.

And remember to `close()` your image after processing.