# Convert android.media.Image (YUV_420_888) to Bitmap

Tags: android, bitmap, android-camera, yuv

I'm trying to implement camera preview image data processing using camera2 api as proposed here: [Camera preview image data processing with Android L and Camera2 API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25462277/camera-preview-image-data-processing-with-android-l-and-camera2-api).

I successfully receive callbacks using onImageAvailableListener, but for future processing I need to obtain bitmap from YUV_420_888 android.media.Image. I searched for similar questions, but none of them helped.

Could you please suggest me how to convert android.media.Image (YUV_420_888) to Bitmap or maybe there's a better way of listening for preview frames?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I write some code about this, and it's the YUV datas preview and chang it to JPEG datas ,and I can use it to save as bitmap ,byte[] ,or others.(You can see the class "Allocation" ). 
And SDK document says: 
"For efficient YUV processing with android.renderscript: Create a RenderScript Allocation with a supported YUV type, the IO_INPUT flag, and one of the sizes returned by getOutputSizes(Allocation.class), Then obtain the Surface with getSurface()." 
here is the code, hope it will help you:https://github.com/pinguo-yuyidong/Camera2/blob/master/camera2/src/main/rs/yuv2rgb.rs

Answer (score 11):

You can do this using the built-in Renderscript intrinsic, [`ScriptIntrinsicYuvToRGB`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/renderscript/ScriptIntrinsicYuvToRGB.html). Code taken from [Camera2 api Imageformat.yuv_420_888 results on rotated image](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47601824/238753):

> ```
> @Override
> public void onImageAvailable(ImageReader reader)
> {
>     // Get the YUV data
>
>     final Image image = reader.acquireLatestImage();
>     final ByteBuffer yuvBytes = this.imageToByteBuffer(image);
>
>     // Convert YUV to RGB
>
>     final RenderScript rs = RenderScript.create(this.mContext);
>
>     final Bitmap        bitmap     = Bitmap.createBitmap(image.getWidth(), image.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
>     final Allocation allocationRgb = Allocation.createFromBitmap(rs, bitmap);
>
>     final Allocation allocationYuv = Allocation.createSized(rs, Element.U8(rs), yuvBytes.array().length);
>     allocationYuv.copyFrom(yuvBytes.array());
>
>     ScriptIntrinsicYuvToRGB scriptYuvToRgb = ScriptIntrinsicYuvToRGB.create(rs, Element.U8_4(rs));
>     scriptYuvToRgb.setInput(allocationYuv);
>     scriptYuvToRgb.forEach(allocationRgb);
>
>     allocationRgb.copyTo(bitmap);
>
>     // Release
>
>     bitmap.recycle();
>
>     allocationYuv.destroy();
>     allocationRgb.destroy();
>     rs.destroy();
>
>     image.close();
> }
>
> private ByteBuffer imageToByteBuffer(final Image image)
> {
>     final Rect crop   = image.getCropRect();
>     final int  width  = crop.width();
>     final int  height = crop.height();
>
>     final Image.Plane[] planes     = image.getPlanes();
>     final byte[]        rowData    = new byte[planes[0].getRowStride()];
>     final int           bufferSize = width * height * ImageFormat.getBitsPerPixel(ImageFormat.YUV_420_888) / 8;
>     final ByteBuffer    output     = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(bufferSize);
>
>     int channelOffset = 0;
>     int outputStride = 0;
>
>     for (int planeIndex = 0; planeIndex < 3; planeIndex++)
>     {
>         if (planeIndex == 0)
>         {
>             channelOffset = 0;
>             outputStride = 1;
>         }
>         else if (planeIndex == 1)
>         {
>             channelOffset = width * height + 1;
>             outputStride = 2;
>         }
>         else if (planeIndex == 2)
>         {
>             channelOffset = width * height;
>             outputStride = 2;
>         }
>
>         final ByteBuffer buffer      = planes[planeIndex].getBuffer();
>         final int        rowStride   = planes[planeIndex].getRowStride();
>         final int        pixelStride = planes[planeIndex].getPixelStride();
>
>         final int shift         = (planeIndex == 0) ? 0 : 1;
>         final int widthShifted  = width >> shift;
>         final int heightShifted = height >> shift;
>
>         buffer.position(rowStride * (crop.top >> shift) + pixelStride * (crop.left >> shift));
>
>         for (int row = 0; row < heightShifted; row++)
>         {
>             final int length;
>
>             if (pixelStride == 1 && outputStride == 1)
>             {
>                 length = widthShifted;
>                 buffer.get(output.array(), channelOffset, length);
>                 channelOffset += length;
>             }
>             else
>             {
>                 length = (widthShifted - 1) * pixelStride + 1;
>                 buffer.get(rowData, 0, length);
>
>                 for (int col = 0; col < widthShifted; col++)
>                 {
>                     output.array()[channelOffset] = rowData[col * pixelStride];
>                     channelOffset += outputStride;
>                 }
>             }
>
>             if (row < heightShifted - 1)
>             {
>                 buffer.position(buffer.position() + rowStride - length);
>             }
>         }
>     }
>
>     return output;
> }
> ```

Comment: `imageToByteBuffer` is not efficient at all

Comment: @user924 what's the best way of doing that?

Comment: Note that `ScriptIntrinsicYuvToRGB` is wrong for camera preview frames, because it assumes the *video* [BT.610](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YCbCr#ITU-R_BT.601_conversion) color space (where **Y** is in range `[16…235]`).

Answer (score 7):

For a simpler solution see my implementation here:

[Conversion YUV 420_888 to Bitmap (full code)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35994288/5148048)

The function takes the media.image as input, and creates three RenderScript allocations based on the y-, u- and v-planes. It follows the YUV_420_888 logic as shown in this Wikipedia illustration.

[image]

However, here we have three separate image planes for the Y, U and V-channels, thus I take these as three byte[], i.e. U8 allocations. The y-allocation has size width * height bytes, while the u- and v-allocatons have size width * height/4 bytes each, reflecting the fact that each u-byte covers 4 pixels (ditto each v byte).