# Has anyone managed to obtain a YUV_420_888 frame using RenderScript and the new Camera API?

Tags: android, android-camera, android-5.0-lollipop, renderscript, yuv

I'm using RenderScript and Allocation to obtain YUV_420_888 frames from the Android Camera2 API, but once I copy the byte[] from the Allocation I receive only the Y plane from the 3 planes which compose the frame, while the U and V planes values are set to 0 in the byte[]. I'm trying to mimic the onPreviewframe from the previos camera API in order to perform in app processing of the camera frames. My Allocation is created like:

```
Type.Builder yuvTypeBuilderIn = new Type.Builder(rs, Element.YUV(rs));
    yuvTypeBuilderIn.setX(dimensions.getWidth());
    yuvTypeBuilderIn.setY(dimensions.getHeight());
    yuvTypeBuilderIn.setYuvFormat(ImageFormat.YUV_420_888);
    allocation = Allocation.createTyped(rs, yuvTypeBuilderIn.create(),
            Allocation.USAGE_IO_INPUT | Allocation.USAGE_SCRIPT);
```

while my script looks like:

```
#pragma version(1)
#pragma rs java_package_name(my_package)
#pragma rs_fp_relaxed

rs_allocation my_frame;
```

Answer (score 7):

The Android sample app HdrViewfinderDemo uses RenderScript to process YUV data from camera2.

https://github.com/googlesamples/android-HdrViewfinder

Specifically, the [ViewfinderProcessor](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-HdrViewfinder/blob/master/Application/src/main/java/com/example/android/hdrviewfinder/ViewfinderProcessor.java) sets up the Allocations, and [hdr_merge.rs](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-HdrViewfinder/blob/master/Application/src/main/rs/hdr_merge.rs) reads from them.

Answer (score 3):

Yes I did it, since I couldn't find anything useful. But I didn't go the proposed way of defining an allocation to the surface. Instead I just converted the output of the three image planes to RGB. The reason for this approach is that I use the YUV420_888 data twofold. First on a high frequency basis just the intensity values (Y). Second, I need to make some color Bitmaps too. Thus, the following solution. The script takes about 80ms for a 1280x720 YUV_420_888 image, maybe not ultra fast, but ok for my purpose.

UPDATE: I deleted the code here, since I wrote a more general solution here [YUV_420_888 -> Bitmap conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36212904/5148048) that takes into account pixelStride and rowStride too.

Answer (score 2):

I think that you can use an ImageReader to get the frames of you camera into YUV_420_888

```
reader = ImageReader.newInstance(previewSize.getWidth(), previewSize.getHeight(), ImageFormat.YUV_420_888, 2);
```

Then you set an OnImageAvailableListener to the reader :

```
 reader.setOnImageAvailableListener(new ImageReader.OnImageAvailableListener() {
            @Override
            public void onImageAvailable(ImageReader reader) {
             int jump = 4; //Le nombre d'image à sauter avant d'en traiter une, pour liberer de la mémoire
             Image readImage = reader.acquireNextImage();

             readImage.getPlane[0] // The Y plane
             readImage.getPlane[1] //The U plane
             readImage.getPlane[2] //The V plane

             readImage.close();
            }
        }, null);
```

Hope that will help you

Comment: Hi. I already tried your sollution. It was one of the first things I tried but after receiving about 50 frames it stops and throws some error.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using almost the same method as widea in their answer.

The exception you keep getting after ~50 frames might be due to the fact that you're processing all the frames by using [acquireNextImage](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/ImageReader.html#acquireNextImage()). The documentation suggest to:

> Warning: Consider using acquireLatestImage() instead, as it will automatically release older images, and allow slower-running processing routines to catch up to the newest frame. [..]

So in case your exception is a IllegalStateException, switching to [acquireLatestImage](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/ImageReader.html#acquireLatestImage()) might help.

And make sure you call close() on all images retrieved from ImageReader.