# how to get RGB values from byte[] array in android camera2 when ImageFormat is JPEG?

Tags: android, camera2

I'm using camera2 API I'm interested in getting RGB value from byte array actually average of RGB values can I get it from this part when byte array is collected from ByteBuffer and gets written in file with FileOutputStream.write(bytes)

**Here is my code:**

```
ByteBuffer byteBuffer = mImage.getPlanes()[0].getBuffer();
byte[] bytes = new byte[byteBuffer.remaining()]; 
byteBuffer.get(bytes); 
FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = null; 
try {  
     fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(mImageFile);    
     fileOutputStream.write(bytes); 
} 
catch (FileNotFoundException e) {  
   // TODO Auto-generated catch block  e.printStackTrace(); } catch    
   (IOException e) {  
          // TODO Auto-generated catch block  e.printStackTrace(); 
   } 
finally {  
    mImage.close();  
    try {   
       fileOutputStream.close();  
    } 
    catch (IOException e) {   // TODO Auto-generated catch block  
        e.printStackTrace();  
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The [`Image`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/Image.html) class reference page implies that [this `BitmapFactory` method](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.html#decodeByteArray(byte[],%20int,%20int)) might be what you're looking for, to convert the JPEG format data to a `Bitmap`.

However, if you don't need the data to be in JPEG format for saving to a file as well (i.e. if you're simply processing images from the camera in the app), you may want to consider changing the output `Surface` format from `JPEG` to `YUV_420_888`. Then you can convert that to RGB `Bitmap` (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28430024/convert-android-media-image-yuv-420-888-to-bitmap)) and save the considerable amount of time it takes to encode JPEG.