# How to get SurfaceTexture content to cpu memory in a inffient way replace glReadpixel with Android NDK or SDK?

Tags: android, opengl-es, android-ndk, surface, glsurfaceview

SurfaceTexture is a very convenient way to direct Android's Camera output to a texture in GLSurfaceView. But I need the pixel data of the surface and the only way I found is via GLES20.glReadPixels which is slow.

Some information says a SurfaceTexture is backed by an external texture which realted to  [EGLImage](https://www.khronos.org/registry/gles/extensions/OES/OES_EGL_image_external.txt).But it seems that Android NDK and SDK dosen't provide too much api about it.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32727163/295004

Comment: On NDK side, I tried to AImageReader with NDK Camera API, which has interface to read out pixels ( still WIP, follow function PresentImage() ): https://github.com/googlesamples/android-ndk/blob/camera-sample/camera/read-image/read-image/src/main/cpp/image_reader.cpp.