# Why is Android's ImageReader class so slow?

Tags: android-camera2, android, image-reader, opencv

I tried OpenCV for Android 3.4.1's brand new `JavaCamera2View` but it was too slow(~15fps for just showing camera view). When I tried the older `JavaCameraView` instead, it gave me good results(~30fps, which is the limit of my camera).

I wondered the reason why Camera2 version was so slow and looked into the implementation. I commented out all processings and renderings of the image (just letting the camera draw to internal `ImageReader` object and then reading it off using `acquireLastImage()` method) and it was still 15 fps. However, when I changed the target surface from `ImageReader` object to the surface of the view itself, it suddenly gave me 30 fps.

So the question is, why is `ImageReader` class so slow? 
My guess is that ImageReader is reading image from Surface, which uses OpenGL, with `glReadPixels()` and this is very slow because it requires the image to be transferred from GPU memory to CPU memory (or possibly it is waiting for GPU flush?), but I cannot be sure because what `ImageReader` does is all hidden in native code.

Or instead is `ImageReader` just fine and is OpenCV missing something?

I'm using ASUS Zenfone 4 Max, Android 7.1.1.

Comment: Because I only want it run in my own android cellphone and I will want fine control over camera device in the future, I don't want to fall back on `JavaCameraView`.

Comment: Please read https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/11261. TL;NR: this may be due to frame size, color conversion, or limited camera2 support on your device.

Comment: I don't think it is frame size or camera2 support problem because when I draw directly to a surface, or when I draw to OpenGL texture, I get good performance. I also commented out YUV420 to ARGB conversion and it is still the same.

Answer (score 0):

I guess it's somehow related to LEGACY camera HAL. I recently bumped into this problem too and actually if you just use `glReadPixel` you can achieve better frame rate than ImageReader. Check this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/51083567/2606068