# CaptureSessions for video recording and image processing using Android camera2 API

Tags: android, image-processing, video, android-camera2

I am building a camera app (using camera2 api) that handles three tasks. It previews the current image in a `TextureView` as part of a `Fragment`. Secondly, it forwards single images to a second instance that allows further processing (using JavaCV or openCV in native JNI) and finally it records and stores the video stream.

I started out with the camera example for the camera2 API that allows saving an image via an ImageReader and extended the feature of processing single images when they become available.
Sources: [Camera2Basic](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-Camera2Basic),
[ImageReader onAvailable processing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25462277/camera-preview-image-data-processing-with-android-l-and-camera2-api/43564630#43564630)

For the recording I've read about how to feed camera data into a `MediaCodec` or `MediaRecorder` process. The thing that confuses me now is the following:

What is the most efficient way in camera2 to manage memory for these tasks (single image processing, video recording) without copying data too often. 
Does the API want developers to add more targets to the previewRequestBuilder as well as surfaces to the capture session or is it preferred to use a single thread pipeline that works on images and stores them in a `Bytebuffer` that keeps all frames of the video?

```
mRequestBuilder = mCameraDevice.createCaptureRequest(CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_RECORD);

// This is the output Surface 
Surface surface = new Surface(texture);
Surface mImageSurface = mImageReader.getSurface();

// Add the new target to CaptureRequest.Builder
mRequestBuilder.addTarget(surface);  // preview in TextureView
mRequestBuilder.addTarget(mImageSurface); // used for image processing
// TODO: need video recording target or usage of 
//       one target for image processing and video recording?

// Here, we create a CameraCaptureSession for camera preview.
mCameraDevice.createCaptureSession(Arrays.asList(surface, mImageSurface), new CameraCaptureSession.StateCallback(){...});
```

Comment: sh_ did you able to get the best method? I'm also looking for similar task. Currently planing to do get the Buffer using ImageReader, process it and feed it to Media Codec. Problem is byte buffer conversion is taxing .. for every new device I have to verify the conversion. Any ideas will be of great help