# Display and capture pre-processed images

Tags: android, opencv, android-camera2

I am using [Android Camera2 sample](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-Camera2Basic) to display and capture pre-processed images. However, I am not being able to do both tasks with the same `ImageReader.OnImageAvailableListener`. When `onImageAvailable(ImageReader reader)` is called for capturing, it can not read the image. I followed @AngeloS answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25462277/camera-preview-image-data-processing-with-android-l-and-camera2-api).

Even if I think that I can work around this, I am not sure if this is the best way to accomplish my end goal. Basically, I want to convert the image to grayscale, do some more preprocessing steps, and extract keypoints from the image using ORB/SIFT/SURF. I want the user to see the preview with preprocessing steps and be able to press capture when he wants. After that, I will extract keypoints from the saved image. I know that processing and displaying in a Texture will be slow, but I think it is feasible.

Summary: is this a good approach? Is it feasible? If yes, is there a way to solve this (capture after preprocessed display)? If you think I am lost, teach me :)

Comment: I'm using Renderscript now to preprocess the image. It works nicely and it is fast, but I'm still not able to capture a picture.

Comment: Solved  it. I will post the solution after presenting my work. Basically, I have created 2 `PreProcessor` instances, one that is only used in capture mode and another that is used in preview mode. `Prepocessor` applies the pre-processing to every frames that it receives in an input Allocation and writes the result in an  output Allocation. I will provide a github link next week.